# Which version will be called if I have included both cPython 2.7.15 and Anaconda Python 3.6.5 to my path (Win10)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

I have both `cPython 2.7.15` and `Anaconda Python 3.6.5` installed on my system. The former is installed under `C:\Python27` while the latter is installed under `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3`.

Currently, I only have a reference to `Anaconda Python 3.6.5` in my `PATH` as `C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3`. If I were to include a reference to `cPython 2.7.15` also in my `PATH` with `C:\Python27`, which version would be called when I type `python` at the command prompt. (the executable in both cases is called `python.exe`)

Comment: The one in the folder that is placed earlier in your `PATH`.

Comment: @Klaus D. : is there then any way for me to switch between the two, as one can between `cPython 2.7` and `cPython 3.6`, wherein the executables have different names?

Comment: Use virtual environments.